# Javascript: Can the elements contained in document.forms["myForm"] be stored in a variable for easy reference?

Tags: javascript

Instead of:

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["dob"].value;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
var z = document.forms["myForm"]["height"].value;
```

I wish to type something like this:

```
var form = document.forms["myForm"];
var x = form.["dob"].value;
var y = form.["dob"].value;
var z = form.["dob"].value;
```

Comment: Did you *try* the thing you "wish to type"?  Did it not work in some way?

Comment: You have the same thing - `form.["dob"].value` assigned to `x, y, z`, what exactly you want to get?

Comment: Yes, you can assign values to variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

```
var form = document.forms["myForm"];
var x = form["dob"].value;
var y = form["age"].value;
var z = form["height"].value;
```

Comment: The code example seems to be exactly the same what the OP has. If yes, why did you copy it? If no, what's the difference?

Comment: It's not exactly the same form["dob"] is not the same as form.["dob"]

Comment: Ah I missed that. Why didn't you explain that in your answer? You shouldn't expect that readers can discern differences in code and even if they can, understand *why* you made that change. A proper explanation is much more valuable than "try this".